# Haskell parse error

Tags: haskell

I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. I am stuck and I can't make anymore progress.

I put the error message I get in my code in comment.
If time allows, could someone please check my eval function? I think I am doing something terribly wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: `eval e (Let [x] y) = let (let fst x = snd x) = y`  What do you mean that line to do?  That isn't even syntactically correct.  The use `let` is invalid with an `in EXPR` (except in do notation, but that's just sugar).

Comment: I ment let is invalid _without_ in.

Comment: okay. If you look at the test cases in main, eval takes env, and exp. env has the form of [(String, Value)]. String becomes a variable which has a value of Value, and that variable goes into env... that's what I meant. But I guess that's not what my code means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell: parse error on input \`='](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657759/haskell-parse-error-on-input)

Comment: I must have misunderstood what Let exactly does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Let` handler will need to extend the environment with the new bindings, and then evaluate the expression with that new environment.

Your environment is a list of name, `Value` pairs, but the `Let` contains a list of name, `Exp` pairs, so you will need to convert the `Exp`s into `Value`s in order to extend the environment.  Note that `eval` converts an `Exp` into a `Value`.

However, since the `Let` can hold multiple bindings, you will need to decide whether the `Exp`s are evaluated in parallel, or sequentially (the difference between `let` and `let*` in lisp).  Can a binding affect the value of following bindings?  Depending upon the answer to that question, you will find yourself using either `map` or `foldl` to transform the list.

Your problem with the evaluation of `Primitive`s is twofold.  First, you are using a pattern which will only match against a list of exactly one element, but your primitives obviously take different numbers of arguments.  The pattern should not use list syntax, since the `Primitive` constructor guarantees that there will be a list in that position.  Instead, you should use a pattern that matches anything (like plain `y`).  Second, the `prim` function is expecting a list of `Value`s, but the `Primitive` constructor contains a list of `Exp`, so you will need to convert them (however, since evaluation of the arguments does not affect the environment, you will be using `map`).

To get you going in the right direction, in:

```
eval e (Primitive x [y]) = prim x [eval e y]
```

the `[y]` pattern will match only a single element list, with that element bound to `y`, and `[eval e y]` is going to result in a single element list.  What you want is a pattern that matches the whole list, and then you want to transform that list by applying `eval e` to each element of that list.

The `eval` of `If` also has problems.  The condition, the then, and the else are all of type `Exp`, but eval is supposed to return a `Value`, so you will have to transform something.  Finally, the haskell `if` wants the condition to be a haskell `Bool`, but your condition is an `Exp`.  You will need to evaluate the `Exp` into a `Value`, and then somehow extract a haskell `Bool` from the `Value`.  Do you want `Number` and `String` `Value`s to behave like `Bool`s in your language (like python), or should only `Bool` `Value`s behave like `Bool`s?

Finally, finally, if you have any type errors (like trying to `Add` a `String` to a `Number`), or you supply the wrong number of arguments to a primitive, you are going to get a pattern match failure from the `prim` function (and possibly in the code you will have to write to extract a `Bool` from your `If` condition).  That may or may not be what you want...

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy and detailed explanation, but I still don't understand something about primitive. That is, if I have "Primitive Add [(Literal (Number 13)), (Literal (Number 12))])" this will cause "prim Add [ e exp]." The exp is not a list in prim, so it takes only one exp, although I have two. So, because of that even this simple test case won't run with my code.

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy and detailed explanation, but I still don't understand something about primitive. That is, if I have "Primitive Add [(Literal (Number 13)), (Literal (Number 12))])" this will cause "prim Add [ e exp]." The exp is not a list in prim, so it takes only one exp, although I have two. So, because of that even this simple test case won't run with my code.

Comment: The `Primitive` constructor takes an `Op` and a list of `Exp`.  In your `eval` function, you can pattern match on the `Primitive` constructor as `eval env (Primitive op args) = ...`, so that the `Op` will be bound to `op`, and the list of `Exp` will be bound to `args`.  The `prim` function wants a list of `Value`s, so you will need to map `eval` over the args with `map (eval env) args`.  You can then pass `op`, and the resulting list of `Value`s to `prim`. i.e. `eval env (Primitive op args) = prim op $ map (eval env) args`.

Comment: what you said logically makes perfect sense. But that causes this error: " Couldn't match expected type `Value' with actual type `[b0]'" I don't understand why. eval return Value and prim takes a list of Values as its argument, so it should work I don't know why it doesnt. This is what I typed. eval e (Primitive x [y]) = prim x [map (eval e) y]

Comment: I wasn't trying to be vague or give hints.  The exact line of code you need is what I wrote at the end of my previous comment!  Maybe the dollar sign is tripping you up.  It is equivalent to the following: `eval env (Primitive x y) = prim x (map (eval env) y)`.  Please note that there is not a square-bracket in sight.

Comment: Your `Let` handler is still messed up too.  It will only match when there is a single binding, and then proceeds to ignore the binding and evaluate the expression.  Try something like: `eval env (Let bs exp) = eval (map (\(lhs,rhs) -> (lhs, eval env rhs)) bs ++ env) exp`

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel very stupid. I really appreciate your help. That works. I need to try to understand your Let code though. You are my savior. I could have not finished without your help. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Cool.  I created a cleaned up version [here](http://pastebin.com/BnfZJaLk), but it will only stay there for 1 day.  Note that the single-quote prime characters are tripping up the syntax hilighter.

Comment: It's a shame all I can do is just say thank you, but I really mean it. Thanks a ton. You made my experience of learning Haskell much less miserable. :)

Answer (score 3):

as Thomas M. DuBuisson already said, your let expression has invalid syntax. Second you really have to be aware what type of arguments function takes and what type it returns. You can not mix Exp with Value, for example - where Exp type is expected you have always pass value of Exp type etc.

```
eval :: Env -> Exp -> Value
-- the return type is Value
-- what are you trying to do here ? extract Value from x ...
eval e (Let [x] y) = eval e $ snd x
-- ... or from y ? Both x & y are of Exp type.
eval e (Let [x] y) = eval e y
```

There are also more type errors in your code:

```
eval e (Primitive x [y]) = prim x [y]
-- prim expects 2nd argument of [Value] type so it can be written as
eval e (Primitive x [y]) = prim x [eval e y]
-- dtto, mixing different types is wrong
eval e (If x y z) = if x then y else z
eval e (If x y z) = let Bool x' = eval e x in
                        if x' then (eval e y) else (eval e z)
```

and finally main expects `IO ()` as the return type so you have to reflect this somehow, like printing the eval result:

```
print $ eval [("y", (Number 40))] (Let [("x", (Literal (Number 2)))] (Primitive Add [(Variable "x"), (Variable "y")]))
```

Comment: I would also like to warn about the expression `[x]` on the left side of an equation, ie. *pattern matching* on the list type, matches lists of exactly **one** element only.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been agonizing over 5 hours on this assignment. But when I run it, I get this message: "Non-exhaustive patterns in function eval." How am I supposed to handle this error? and what does this error mean? Thank you so much.

Comment: I see what the problem is. When I run that test case, that's going to crash when it hits "eval e (Variable x) = fromJust (lookup x e)," because it returns nothing. The "e" which means environment should contain more than a single tuple, but I have no idea how to add tuples to that, and I am afraid that that'd violate the Env condition, which is "type Env = [(String, Value)]." I suppose that it means it can contain only one tuple in the list, right?

Comment: "eval e (Primitive x [y]) = prim x [eval e y]" I think this code causes a lot of problems, because [y] is a list of Expressions, and the code turn it into just a single expression.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
let e' = {- extend env with x -} in eval e' y
```